# Grouping of search results in a django template

Tags: python, django

I have a search results page in django.  The results list a video title, video description and some meta data.  It also includes the topic the video is in.

Instead of returning a full list of videos, I would like to try grouping my results by topic. Then, within each group, only show the top 1-3, with a link to "view all x videos in y topic"  The determining factor of whether to show 1, 2, or 3 in the group would be a calculation based on the total number.  So if there are under 10, only show 1 video in that grouping.  If there are between 10-30 in the group, show 2 videos.  If 30 or more in that grouping, show 3.  (Determining 1-3 might not be necessary, I would be ok doing top 3)

My code is currently pretty simple to just return results.  But I can't figure out how to get the groupings set up within django's template language.  I guess I could do this in my view but hoping there's some simple filters I'm not aware of to help and do it in the template.  Thanks for any advice..  Here's my current code:

```
<h4>Search Results</h4>
        <p>{{ res.hits.total }} matches found for <span id="qresult">{% if q %}'{{ q }}'{% else %}all{% endif %}</span></p>
    </div>
    <ul class="search-list" id="search-results">
    {% if res.hits.total > 0 %}
        {% for h in reshh %}
            {% with h|get_underscore_value:"_source" as source %}
                <li><a href='/video/{{ source.slug }}'>{{ source.title }}</a>
                <p>{{ source.description }}</p>
                <span class="sr-meta" style="">metadata</span>
                <p>(topic: {{ source.topic_name }})</p></li>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
```

btw it's pulling from elasticsearch.  res.hits.hits._source is where my results are contained.  The "get_underscore_value" is just a custom filter to get around django complaining that my variable begins with an underscore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `regroup` templatetag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup